# ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<LayoutData> above this SchedulingPage Widget using layoutBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm getting a providerNotFoundException, and I suspect that there is a context mismatch in the below code, but I'm having a hard time seeing it.  As I understand, problems with BuilderContext arise when an .of method is performed within the same build method, but I don't see this happening in this case.  Some of the Provider.of methods work fine as annotated in the below code, but as soon as SchedulingPage is called, the Provider.of methods no longer work.

What is the problem here?

Edit: I updated to use my full code below:
Here's the full error: ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this LoginForm Widget

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Home(),
  );
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CalendarData()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => LayoutData()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          print("constraints: $constraints");
          Size mediaSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
          double safeAreaSize = mediaSize.height - constraints.maxHeight;
          Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).safeAreaDiff = safeAreaSize;
          Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).safeArea = constraints;
          Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).mediaArea = mediaSize;
          var test = Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).mediaArea.width;
          print(test);  // this works

          return Scaffold(body: LoginScreen());
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double test = Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).mediaArea.width;
        print("test: $test");  // this works
        return LoginForm();
      }
    }

    class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
      LoginForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
    }

    class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double width = Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).mediaArea.width; // The code fails here
        print('width: $width');
        return Text("this is where it fails ^^^^^^^^");
      }
    }

    class LayoutData with ChangeNotifier {
      double safeAreaDiff = 0.0;
      BoxConstraints safeArea;
      Size mediaArea;

      LayoutData() {
        initializeApp();
      }

      void initializeApp() {
        print("layout initialized");
      }
    }
```

Comment: It should works, can you paste your entire code ?

Comment: ok.  I pasted the entire code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access provider in same class in which you create. That must be parent widget.

```
void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CalendarData()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => LayoutData()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          print("constraints: $constraints");
          Size mediaSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
          double safeAreaSize =
              mediaSize.height - constraints.maxHeight; // works
          Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).safeAreaDiff =
              safeAreaSize; // works
          Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).safeArea = constraints; // works
          Provider.of<LayoutData>(context).mediaArea = mediaSize; // works
          Provider.of<CalendarData>(context).working = "beer"; // works
          print(Provider.of<CalendarData>(context).working); // works

          return Scaffold(body: SchedulingPage());
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,181ms.
I/flutter (25187): constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=659.4)
I/flutter (25187): layout initialized
I/flutter (25187): 411.42857142857144
I/flutter (25187): test: 411.42857142857144
I/flutter (25187): width: 411.42857142857144
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it didn't help.  I've updated my code above with your suggestion, but I still have the error.

Comment: @WilliamTerrill it is working completely fine. i test in my device. i am adding output of code in my answer. try flutter clean and again run app.

Comment: I went ahead and gave you the selected answer because you're right. I ran the code above in a brand new project, and it worked fine.  Even with flutter clean, the problem persists, so I now think that the error I'm seeing is caused by something more fundamental.  If/when I figure it out, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this on the off chance that someone has the same problem that I did. It turned out the issue was not fixed by the chosen solution. The code, as written should have worked.  However, in this case, the solution was difficult to find. It turned out that the import itself was incorrect.  There were two imports of the Provider Data Class, like this:

```
import 'package:myProject/providers/CalendarData.dart';
```

and

```
import 'package:gcfdlayout2/Providers/CalendarData.dart';
```

This ambiguity confused the IDE, I believe, and, although it didn't give me any errors at build time, it did at run time, but the "could not find Provider" made me assume that it couldn't find the Provider in the Tree, not in the code itself.

The way I finally found this was to use other methods of running the code.  Initially, I was only using Visual Studio Code, but I never got any errors that suggested it was an import problem.  I changed to Android Studio, and it informed me that there were two imports for the CalendarData class.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried placing your MultiProvider() above your MaterialApp()?

Comment: i did that, it is not working, can you explain more ?